# How can I calculate a transformation matrix that maps a curve to another

Tags: c#, image-processing, affinetransform

As shown in the picture below, I have two curves: curveB (extracted from an Image) and curveA (reference curve). each curve is represented as an array of 2D points.

[image]

I am trying to find out:

1. is curveB part of curveA? (curveB may be transformed under some
   affine transformation)
2. which transformation matrix maps curveB to
   the appropriate position on curveA?
3. is there a c# library that do 1 & 2 for me?!

any help will be appreciated